# Link checker using Go channels

Tags: beginner, http, concurrency, go, web-scraping

I've started to learn Golang and channels in it.
I decided to write simple application - recursive link checker. Given some URL it tries to retrieve pages, parses them and goes deeper.

Here's a code of first version.

Some questions:

1. I use counter `urlsInProcess` to understand when all tasks are done. But it looks a little bit awkward, isn't it?
2. I launch manually several parsers and fetchers. Should I use here WaitGroups?
3. Not sure about error treatment. How to do it better?
4. How effective is variable transmitting between goroutines? Are there some unnecessary copying?
5. Has it some race conditions? For example can program got message from channel `chanTasksFinished` before than from channel `chanTasksToFetch`? In this case we will exit before all tasks are done.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

type url string
type TaskStatus int

const (
    _ TaskStatus = iota
    TaskStatusNew
    TaskStatusToParse
)

type Task struct {
    url
    depth int
    resp  *http.Response
    //body *[]byte
}

var chanTasksToFetch = make(chan Task)
var chanTasksToParse = make(chan Task)
var chanFetchersIn = make(chan Task)
var chanTasksFinished = make(chan Task)

var mainWait = make(chan interface{})

var data = make(map[url]Task)

func getHref(t html.Token) (ok bool, href string) {
    // iterate over all of the token's attribs
    for _, a := range t.Attr {
        if a.Key == "href" {
            return true, a.Val
        }
    }
    return
}

func extractLinks(page string) (urls []url) {
    // extracts links from page and sends them into the url_channel
    tokenizer := html.NewTokenizer(strings.NewReader(page))
    for {
        token_type := tokenizer.Next()
        switch {
        case token_type == html.ErrorToken:
            log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Error token_type: %s. Error: %s", token_type, tokenizer.Err()))
            return
        case token_type == html.StartTagToken:
            token := tokenizer.Token()
            if token.Data == "a" { // it's a link
                log.Println("Link token: ", token)
                _, href := getHref(token)
                log.Println("A href=", href)
                urls = append(urls, url(href))
                log.Println("A href sent")
            }
        }
    }
}

func parser(inChannel chan Task, toChannel chan Task) {
    for task := range inChannel {
        bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(task.resp.Body)
        defer task.resp.Body.Close()
        var urls []url = extractLinks(string(bytes))
        for _, u := range urls {
            toChannel <- Task{url: u, depth: task.depth}
        }
        // after task is parsed we think it's done
        chanTasksFinished <- task

    }
}

func parsers(inChannel chan Task, toChannel chan Task) {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go parser(inChannel, toChannel)
    }

}

// Fetches given Task and passes to channel
// inChannel - channel from which get new tasks
// toChannel - channel to which send fetched tasks
func fetcher(inChannel chan Task, toChannel chan Task) {
    for task := range inChannel {
        log.Println("Fetcher got task", task)
        resp, err := http.Get(string(task.url))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Got error on url '%s': %s", task.url, err))
        }
        task.resp = resp
        log.Println("Fetcher sends to channel", task)
        toChannel <- task
    }
}

// Launches fetcher tasks
func fetchers(inChannel chan Task, toChannel chan Task) {
    //var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go fetcher(inChannel, toChannel)
    }
}

func taskDispatcher() {
    log.Println("URL dispatcher started")
    var urlsInProcess int = 0
LOOP:
    for {
        var task Task
        select {
        case task = <-chanTasksToFetch:
            log.Println("TaskDispatcher got task to fetch", task)
            if task.depth <= 0 {
                log.Println("Depth is over for task", task)
                continue
            }
            task.depth--
            if _, present := data[task.url]; present {
                // already here
                log.Println("Task is already in map", task)
                continue
            }
            // add task to map and launch it
            data[task.url] = task
            urlsInProcess++
            chanFetchersIn <- task
        case task = <-chanTasksFinished:
            log.Println("Task finished: ", task)
            if _, present := data[task.url]; !present {
                log.Println("Finished task was not found in map!", task)
            }
            data[task.url] = task
            urlsInProcess--
        }
        log.Println("Now urls in process", urlsInProcess)
        if urlsInProcess == 0 {
            log.Println("Time to exit from taskDispatcher")
            mainWait <- nil
            break LOOP
        }
    }
    log.Println("taskDispatcher finished")
}

func main() {
    go taskDispatcher()
    go fetchers(chanFetchersIn, chanTasksToParse)
    go parsers(chanTasksToParse, chanTasksToFetch)
    chanTasksToFetch <- Task{url: "http://www.ru", depth: 2}
    log.Println("wainting in mainWait")
    <-mainWait
    log.Println("Main exit")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reading the whole body to transform it later to a Reader (again):

```
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(task.resp.Body)
    defer task.resp.Body.Close()
    var urls []url = extractLinks(string(bytes))

(...)

func extractLinks(page string) (urls []url) {
    // extracts links from page and sends them into the url_channel
    tokenizer := html.NewTokenizer(strings.NewReader(page))
```

You could simply do

```
    var urls []url = extractLinks(resp.Body)

(...)

func extractLinks(body io.ReadCloser) (urls []url) {
    defer body.Close()
    // extracts links from page and sends them into the url_channel
    tokenizer := html.NewTokenizer(body)
```

---

When you parse the URL, you just take the `href`. If it is a relative link (or a `/question/123`), you won't be able to parse it further. I might need to use the [`url.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) function (beware of names collision with your `url` type)

---

Instead of an `int` for `urlsInProcess`, you could use a [`WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) with `wg.Add(1)` and `.Done()` instead of `++` and `--`.
You could then return this waitgroup, for the caller to do `wg.Wait()` (but then you won't be able to know how many urls are currently in the work).

Comment: This blog post is also worth a read: https://appliedgo.net/flow2go/. And in this style (flow) I particularly like the way [Egon](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/vgj_d-MjUHA/T9sE64Yrcq0J) implemented it: https://play.golang.org/p/Mq_eROYm-X. He let the `New***()` create the output channels and connects them together `split.In = hello.Out` in the main